# Use Series names as xAxis in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I want to use my series names as xAxis. I have tried it like the code below. This code is creating multiple series but only one x axis value. Let's say in my code I want to create series for every fund and plot fund values in xAxis as well.

```
    function draw(fund, zreturn) {

    zreturn = [12.75, 11.77, 13.76];
    fund = ['abc', 'xyz', 'pqr'];

    var options = {};
    options = {

        chart: {
            renderTo: 'graphDiv',
            type: 'line',
            Height: '400px'

        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Fund Performance Graph',
            x: -20
        },

        subtitle: {
            text: '',
            x: -20
        },

        xAxis: {
            categories: fund
            }
        },

        yAxis: {
            labels: {
                enabled: true,
                format: function () {
                    return (this.value + '%')
                }
            }
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'middle',
            borderWidth: 0,

        },

        series: zreturn.filter(function (zreturn, i) {


            return fund[i]

        }).map(function (zreturn, i) {
            /* Then return as series */
            return {
                //type: 'line',
                name: fund[i],
                data: zreturn,
                dataLabels: {
                    align: 'center',
                    enabled: true,
                    format: "{y:.2f}" + '%',
                    style: {
                        fontSize: "8px",
                        fontFamily: 'Arial',

                    },

                }
            }
        })
    }

    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);

};
```

Comment: I have corrected your code so it will work like you want: http://jsfiddle.net/worg6jLz/26/

Comment: @GrzegorzBlachliński Its working perfectly. could you please explain what you have done?

Comment: I have posted answer with explanation of changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that right now you have small mistakes in your code.

First of all you are using yAxis.labels.format as a function. It should be formatter if you want to use it as a function:

```
yAxis: {
  labels: {
    enabled: true,
    formatter: function() {
      return (this.value + '%')
    }
  }
},
```

Next, you have mistake in your data, it should be an array:

```
data: [
  [i, zreturn]
],
```

I am here adding x value of your point as well as y value. If I will not add x value, points will always start from 0 and because you have added only one point to every series, all of them will be on the first category.

Here you can find an example how your chart may work with these small corrections:
http://jsfiddle.net/worg6jLz/29/